# scrolling a xml

Tags: android, xml, scroll

Hi again earlier i asked about adding images and text and i was told to put it in to a xml.  Now my text goes farther than the xml is there a way i can add a scroll to it or will i have to go about another route to get the effects i need. thanks again.

Comment: A scroll to what exactly? The actual XML? Or the layout that the textviews are in? Just use a scrollview

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was it or not but it was thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, your question really is worded pretty poorly. Assuming you're talking about your XML layout file, just encapsulate your Views into a single ScrollView, i.e.:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout ...>
        <ImageView .../>
        <TextView .../>
    //all the rest of your stuff here
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```